# User environment variables in Angular component to define settings

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following Angular 7 code:

```
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';

const settings : UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: 'https://localhost:5005',
  client_id: 'spa',
  redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/signin',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/signout'
};

@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' 
})

export class AuthService {

  private manager = new UserManager(settings);
  private user: User = null;

  constructor() {

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

  }

  isSignedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

}
```

I need settings like `redirect_uri` to be defined from environment variables.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the issue? You can add it in environment.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the settings within *environment.ts* or *environment.prod.ts*

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiUrl: ' http://127.0.0.1:8000/1.0',
    redirect_uri: '<your_value_here>'
};
```

And then import this in your service:

```
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
```

And then use it wherever in the service you like as a constant.

```
print_redirect_uri() {
    console.log(environment.redirect_uri);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but should I declare UserManagerSettings inside the Component, then inject the environment on the constructor and finally define the settings in Component’s Init?

Comment: No need to inject the environment. Just import it in the service itself, and then import the service into the component and use the service as normal. The UserManagerSettings isn't needed. It can be put into environment.ts  directly.